How to find the relation between the number of photons in the readout resonator and SNR?
Motivated by this thesis (Sections 3.5-3.6, pp. 70-78), I'd like to find a relation between the number of photons in the readout resonator and SNR.
In considered thesis I found two interpretations of $SNR$:
$1.$ The distance between two Gaussian distributions corresponding to $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ states:

$$ SNR = \frac{(x_0-x_1)^2}{2\sigma^2}$$
From this it is clear, that the larger $x_0-x_1$, the better the $SNR$.
$2.$ For considered state:
$$|\psi_f\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\alpha e^{i\phi}\rangle|g\rangle+|\alpha e^{-i\phi}\rangle|e\rangle)$$
the distance between the two dispersed photon states is
$$\delta x = \langle x\rangle_{\alpha exp(i\phi)} - \langle x\rangle_{\alpha exp(-i\phi)} = \frac{1}{2}\langle a + a^{\dagger}\rangle_{\alpha exp(i\phi)} - \frac{1}{2}\langle a + a^{\dagger}\rangle_{\alpha exp(-i\phi)} = 2|\alpha|sin(\phi),$$
where $x$ - some measured value.
Then, assuming $\sigma^2 = 1/4$,
$$SNR = 8|\alpha|^2sin(\phi)^2$$
This interpretation is more complicated for me than the first one, but anyway, even for the last formula I don't have a direct relation between the number of photons in readout resonator and $SNR$. Is it possible to derive it somehow?
